# missing event if not pull event as soon as the event fired from canon eos

Tags: android, events, camera

I am listening event from canon eos camera on android device through usb connection.

As we know, receive event and receive data are both from bulk in endpoint for canon eos, so I can not do these work at same time.

Now I can get event successfully.But there is still a problem, for example, I received a ObjectAdded event, and then I copy the object from camera to my android device, this takes several seconds, after I finished copy work and return to check event on bulk in endpoint, and I find I can not get those events fired during copy work, it seems I should pull event as soon as the event is fired, or I will lost them if I check them later. For nikon, it is not a problem because we get event from interrupt endpoint and get data from in endpoint, and we could always check event from interrupt endpoint without waitting. But what should I do for canon eos?

I am not sure what causes missing event, but I make a test to just only listening events without doing other things like saving photoes:

```
while (isReadingInterruptEvent) {
     if (!isEosPullingImage) {
          List<EosEvent> eosEvents = checkEvents();
          if (eosEvents != null) {
               Log.e("eosEvent:", eosEvents.size() + "");
          }
     }
     Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

I check event every 1 seconds, and I find that the longer interval time is, it is more likely to miss event.